# updating the model based on the new database changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I created a model "user" using the generate scaffold user command line. Next I made some changes to the database using generate migration command line and then updated the database using rake db:migration . Now I want to make my model in sync with the database fields automatically. Is it possible through a command line and if yes, how ? If not, what are the other options.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your application find automacaly the change in your database if you don't specify a attr_accessible in your model. It make SQL requests to see all fields in the table. It's slower but simpler.